ssl верификация подписи GET запроса
Задача написать модуль интеграции, с Интернет эквайрингом Газпромбанка.
На тестовой сборке всё заработало, много раз проверено со всеми условиями...
При переносе на рабочую сборку сайта, перестал работать кусок кода, а именно то место где проводится верификация подписи GET запроса подтверждения платежа.
Пишет такие ошибки:


openssl_verify(): supplied key param cannot be coerced into a public key в функции vircgpb()
Warning: openssl_pkey_get_details() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given в функции vircgpb()
Notice: Undefined index: oper_val в функции vircgpb()


Вроде всё идентично, но результат верификации разный.
Отличие только в URL, куда приходит запрос.
Перерыл почти весь Интернет, но ни чего вразумительного мне не встретилось.
Конечно есть подозрения на некоторое... Но с этим некоторым, работает в тестовой сборке.
(Я про то что сигнатура дергается из:
$sign = $_GET['signature'];
а url из:
$url = $GLOBALS['base_url'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];)

Извиняюсь за корявость написанного, пробую делать первый раз. Надеюсь на подсказку.
Код следующий:
function vircgpb() {

    vircgpb_log('RPReg', true);  
    $url = $GLOBALS['base_url'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    vircgpb_log('$url = ' . $url, true);
    print_r( $url );
    
    if(isset($_GET['trx_id'])){
    $trx_id = $_GET['trx_id'];
    }
    if(!empty($_GET['result_code'])){
    $result_code = $_GET['result_code'];
    }
    //print_r('result_code: '. $result_code );
    if(isset($_GET['signature'])){
    $sign = $_GET['signature'];
    }
    if(!empty($_GET['o_order_id'])){
    $order_id = $_GET['o_order_id'];
    }
    require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/../vircabo/zscripts/payorder-lib.php';
    $order = virc_payorder_get($order_id);
    $paysysSecret = zQuery('pay_online,_pay_online', 'select', $order['paysys_id'], array('zlist'=>1), 2);
    $cert_val = $paysysSecret[0]['oper_val'];
    $data_key = openssl_pkey_get_public($cert_val);
    print_r( $data_key );
    
    // Извлекаем публичный ключ
    $keyData=openssl_pkey_get_details($data_key);
    $pubkeyid=$keyData['key'];
    print_r( $pubkeyid );
    
    // Get check string. Получаем контрольную строку
    $sign_position = strpos($url, '&signature=');
    $verify_string = substr($url, 0, $sign_position);
    
    // Сравниваем сигнатуры
    $resp = openssl_verify($verify_string, base64_decode($sign), $pubkeyid, OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA1);
    print_r(PHP_EOL.'result: '.$resp); //при корректной проверке возвращает result: 1


На тестовом сервере банка перепутали некоторые данные.
В общем код сработал, нее принял кривую подпись. :)

У вас начинаются проблемы в строке
$cert_val = $paysysSecret[0]['oper_val'];

Скорее всего это результат вашего запроса, который возвращает не те данные
и все вытекает из этого.
Проверьте результаты запроса zQuery

Всё верно, этот запрос выводит текст сертификата сохранённого в таблице базы.

Другими способами вытащить текст сертификата, подставляло строку сертификата в ответ, перед ответом xml . Примеров мало когда требуется Xml ответ, на Get запрос. И ещё с поlписью SSL . Сначала пробовал file_get_contents, вытаскивает сертификат подставляя в Get ответ. Вот чем сигнатуры отличаются, в конце : в $url = $GLOBALS['base_url'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; = *******DpTA%3D%3D и в $sign = $_GET['signature']; = ********DpTA== и все прочие такие знаки как // \ переводит проценты и цифры.

@PAFES Текст сертификата должен совпадать в тесте и проде. Если не совпадает, тогда нужно сделать чтобы поле таблицы в котором хранится текст сертификата поддерживал двоичные данные. Какого типа у вас это поле?

Думал над этим, но когда на тестовом заработало, везде оставил тип поля TEXT.
Но тем не менее, на тестовом работает с такими же настройками, ...
Отправил запрос в Банк, может они там чего накосячили... адреса запросов к нам и сертификаты меняли...
